# Proof verification of open sets in metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, solution-verification

Let $(X,d_1)$ be a metric space and let $d_2\colon X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by:
$$
d_2(x,y) = \frac{d_1(x,y)}{1+d_1(x,y)}
$$
Prove that a subset $A \subseteq X$ is open w.r.t $d_2$ iff it is open w.r.t. $d_1$.

Picture below is my proof. Is there anything missing? Incorrectly justified? A better proof? Thanks! I just want to see if I correctly understood how to do proofs involving metric space and open sets.

[image]

Comment: Better would at least be that you type your proof in Latex.

Comment: I see, sorry about that, will try to do so in the future